# There are i have one list List<String> id = ["abc","abc","abc"],how can i parse into json string because i can pass in http.post(body) in flutter

Tags: json, flutter, flutter-http

```
List<String> _productIds = widget.productIds;
String _storeId = widget.storeid;
String jsonProductId = jsonEncode(_productIds); //that give me[\"abc\",\"abc\",\"abc\"]
```

Comment: what you want to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want to pass comma separated String into http request. you can try converting the list to comma separated string.

```
List<String> _productIds = widget.productIds;
String requestString = _productIds .join(', ');
print(s);
```